# GDB: Application compiled with "-g" option but still i am seeing error as "No Symbol table is loaded"

Tags: eclipse, gdb, systemc

I am using Eclipse like interface to build my project.

I have compiled my application with "-g" option and "strip" utility is not used which will remove the debug symbols.
But then as well while loading GDB i see error as

> No Symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command
>
> Function "sc_main" not defined.
>
> No debug symbol data for file ./sc_main.cpp found. Try recompiling this file with the "-g" option to enable debug mode for your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SystemC library built with debug symbols?

You can follow these steps for building SystemC library with debug symbols(UNIX/Linux):

```
$ tar xf systemc-2.3.1a.tar.gz
$ cd systemc-2.3.1a
$ mkdir objdir
$ ../configure --prefix=$HOME/apps/systemc-2.3.1a --enable-debug
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
```

Set the environment variable **"SYSTEMC_HOME"** as below in your **".bashrc"**:

```
export SYSTEMC_HOME=$HOME/apps/systemc-2.3.1a
```

Restart your terminal session to update the environment variable.

- **Note:** Do not delete the source folder as the debug symbols use the base source folder for source level debugging.
- You can provide the prefix any path wherever you want to install the SystemC library.

Comment: **It's not about systemC library, but about the project which i am building based on systemC**.


I am using eclipse to create SystemC based module but the final generated object file has missing debug info(debug sections are not getting generated).

Comment: Are you building with Debug Configuration?  Kindly post your Eclipse Console Build Output Log here.

Comment: Thanks AmeyaVs, now it's working actually i added "-g" compiler option but finally the object file where getting stripped based of the attribute **STRIP_DEBUG_SYMBOLS**.

Earlier this attribute was set to "yes" in config file now i change it to "no" and it's working as expected and the debug info are getting generated into final binary.

Comment: @geek What do you mean by adding "-g" compiler option?  Actually Eclipse already has support for building C/C++ code in Debug and Release mode. Can you share some more details about your build environment?